# Multiprocessing a python script

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I learnt about the multiprocessing tool in python: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html.

Say I have a python program which is complicated and fleshed out, but it does not use up all my cores when running. So it uses 100% of one core and takes forever to complete. It is hard for me to go into the program's code and figure out how to split up the processes manually, simply cause the program is too complicated.

Is it possible to write a simple python script that enables multiprocessing on any python program I specify? To be exact, I want something as simple as this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

Process(myprogram.py)
```

If not, is there a next-best method?

Comment: Is it possible to run more than one instane of the program at the same time? Does it read or write data?

Comment: If the program in question does processing on some dataset and there is no way to inform the program to work on smaller chunks of the dataset; the answer is No. (*There is almost never a silver magic bullet with software development!*).

Comment: @JamesMills ah okay so I definitely need to specify chunks. this is disappointing but also what i realistically expected.

Comment: @Tichodroma Both read and write. It is a machine-learning system, will that help?

Comment: It kind of doesn't matter what the program does; but you need to be able to start N different processes that start work on M different chunks of input data.

Comment: Then it is not possible to run more than instance of the program at the same time. The sooner or later will clash while reading or writing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussion, the straight answer is:

> No.

Simply because multi-processing is not some magical trick that automatically offloads the burden on one processor to another. The developer needs to know how a program should split up a task, and specify that each task should take up a new process.

So ultimately, you have to be in control of your code in order to produce proper and efficient multi-processing.